# Remove padding of characters in UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

I wanna remove this padding because I got a wrong height from textView.contentSize.height (Only Japanese/English).

Do you have a solution or codes for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and solved it as

```
  YourTextField.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-8,0,0); //you can modify these values to best fit your text.
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not my wanted answer. I want to remove padding(margin) of 'characters' not textfield. It might be appeared by Japanese or similar language.

Comment: you have check make UIFont class and make custom font using core text and set font's properties yourself.